# How do I remove lingering potion effects in Minecraft: Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I built a really nice house in a really nice flat world.
I decided I should look through all the items in Creative Mode. I found Lingering Potions, so I splashed healing potions all over my house and some invisibility potions. It looked like fire, but it said that it would only be there for a few minutes.
As I went into Survival Mode, I didn't get any of the effects applied when I stood in the clouds of the potions. It's very laggy and annoying, so please help me. They also look so dumb: I don't want my house looking like it's on fire for the rest of my life.

Just so you know, I don't know a lot of commands.

Answer (score 2):

The command you're looking for would be this one:

```
/kill @e[type=area_effect_cloud]
```

I tested 20 potions, 19 of them lingered for 501 ticks and one lingered for 500 ticks.

500 ticks are 25 seconds.

After some more testing I discovered that lingering potions linger for a shorter time if there is an entity nearby, effectively using the potion. I was able to reduce the duration to only 10 ticks, 0.5 seconds.
This may be the reason for the outlier in my earlier tests.

Items do not decrease the duration for how long the potion lingers.

To remove any potion effects from a player you would use

```
/effect <player> clear
```